# burger menu does not work in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am testing Bootstrap 3.3.5 and I downloaded [this](http://bootswatch.com/journal/) theme and I loaded to my page.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> //theme's css
    <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">//some modifications to colors 
</head>
```

This is the `nav` inside the `body`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blog</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbarcollapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Taken from "Extending Bootstrap" by Christoffer Niska. The website is responsive so, When I downsize the browser , I see the burger basic menu `Ξ` but when I click it, it does not show the menu. I get no errors in the console, so I don't know how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a typo: `#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` does not evaluate to `bs-example-navbarcollapse-1` (missing a dash), and `datatoggle` should be `data-toggle`.  The code works fine with those changes made: https://jsfiddle.net/gxres9o2/

Comment: I am sorry for this. `data-toggle` was my mistake, during copy/paste I guess, but the `navbarcollapse` is also mistyped  in the book. Never trust books again. Thanks Joseph. Wanna make it to an answer, so I can upvote you?

Comment: Questions where the answer is a correction of a typo are typically supposed to be closed because it's unlikely that the answer will be of any use to anyone else in the future, but considering it originated in a book which you provided the name and title to, I can see people finding the question again with the same problem.  I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo: `#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` does not evaluate to `bs-example-navbarcollapse-1` (missing a dash), and `datatoggle` should be `data-toggle`. The code works fine with those changes made: http://jsfiddle.net/gxres9o2